# Is it true that one should not write the universal quantifier behind a statement?

Tags: soft-question, notation, quantifiers

We all know that there are different ways to say that e.g. an element $x$ belongs to each member of a family of sets $(A_j)_{j \in J}$ for some index set $J$. The most common ways I know are the following:

- $\forall j \in J \colon x \in A_j$
- $x \in A_j$ for all $j \in J$
- $x \in A_j \ \forall j \in J$

I think I heared that from some people's point of view the last notation is not considered as "nice". Now my question to the pros outside there is: Is it true that one should not write the universal quantifier behind a statement? Do you recommend using one of the first two notations only? I think there are even some textbooks using the last notation so I am not sure if it is seen as "bad" my most mathematicians. Maybe I am just influenced by some special opinions.

Comment: I use the second one most of the time. Only in a formal setting I would use the first one, or actually $\forall j \in J. x \in A_j$, or even $(\forall j \in J)\, x \in A_j$. I hardly ever see the third one, and never use it.

Comment: The problem comes when there are multiple quantifiers involved. For instance, say you have the statement "$\forall x\in X, \exists \delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subseteq X$" If you write the universal quantifier last, "$\exists \delta>0$ such that $B(x, \delta)\subseteq X \ \forall x \in X$," this can be misconstrued as meaning "$\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x \in X, B(x,\delta)\subseteq X$." Which has a different meaning than the original sentence.

Comment: Yes, this is clear of course. I am only speaking about examples similar to the one I presented.

Comment: My answer is here: [hanging quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207357/21813).

Answer (score 2):

If you use formal notation, you should use it correctly. The rule for $\forall$ and $\exists$ is that they are written to the left of the formula they apply to, just like $\sum$, $\int$ and $\lim$ do; nobody would dream of writing the latter after the formula they apply to. The only reason people would write $\forall$ after the formula is that it is pronounced "for all" and in English a phrase starting with "for all" may come after the statement it applies to (although it might come before as well). I have not seen the same thing happening with $\exists$, and I think this is because in in English a phrase that would start with "there exists an$~x$ such that" when placed before the statement would become "for some$~x$" when placed after the statement, so one cannot place $\exists$ to the right and read it as a simple abbreviation. But neither $\exists$ nor $\forall$ are abbreviations for an English phrase, and they should not be used as such.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you are writing on a blackboard or in a formal article. In a formal article, I would write

> $x$ belongs to $A_j$ for all $j \in J$

to have a fluent sentence. See Halmos' recommendations on [How to write mathematics](http://www.di.ens.fr/~bouillar/Stages/Halmos-How-To-Write.pdf).
On a blackboard, I may simply write

> $x \in \bigcap_{j\in J} A_j$